# Change message priority with MassTransit/RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a queue with 100 messages in. At some point, I'd like send a message but this message has a higher priority and should be treated first, before the 100 existing.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks,

Tried to set the but no more message arrive :
On the sender (Web API)

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
    sbc.Host("hostName", "host", h =>
    {
        h.Username("username");
        h.Password("password);
    })
);

Send the message
Uri uri = new Uri("queue:myQueue");
var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
await endpoint.Send(request);
```

On the consumer (consoler app) :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", e =>
        {
            e.Handler<myType>(context =>
            {
                return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{context.Message.Id}");
            });

        });
    });

    busControl.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Receive listening for messages");

    Console.ReadLine();

    busControl.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When configuring a receive endpoint, you can enable priority for that endpoint (queue):

```cs
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("priority_input_queue", x =>
{
    x.EnablePriority(4);

    x.ConfigureConsumer(...);
});
```

This would configure the endpoint with maximum allowed priority of four (4).

Then, when sending/publishing a message, the priority can be specified:

```cs
await Bus.Publish(new Message(...), context =>
{
    context.SetPriority(2);
});
```

If no value is specified, the default priority is used.

Comment: What update? And you always start the bus, including the one in the web api.

Comment: In my code, I don't see where to set the priority

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I tried with your suggestion but the priority doesn't work. The message is sent to consumer randomly.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson could you please take a look on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645441/set-message-priority-rabbitmq-masstransit. Thank you