# MassTransit - priority queue

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have several questions when using MassTransit with RabbitMq.
I have two queues. One for normal messsages and one for priority messages.
Priority ones must be handled before the normal ones.

Lets say I'm configuring bus this way:

```
    public void ConfigureRabbitMq(IBusRegistrationContext context, IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        var rabbitConfig = RabbitMqConfig.Get<RabbitMqConfiguration>();

        configurator.Host(rabbitConfig.Host, rabbitConfig.VirtualHost, hfg =>
        {
            hfg.Password(rabbitConfig.Password);
            hfg.Username(rabbitConfig.UserName);
        });

        configurator.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 8;

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitConfig.SendQueue, endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.Durable = true;
            endpoint.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 5;
            endpoint.PrefetchCount = 25;
            endpoint.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
            endpoint.ConfigureConsumer<Service.MessageService.Send>(context);
        });

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitConfig.SendPriorityQueue, endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.Durable = true;
            endpoint.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 5;
            endpoint.PrefetchCount = 25;
            endpoint.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
            endpoint.ConfigureConsumer<Service.MessageService.Send>(context);
        });
    }
```

What will 'configurator.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 8;' do?
Is it gonna limit the number of messages for entire app or set limit for every endpoint to 8?

Can I somehow make sure that the messages from 'SendPriorityQueue' are handled before the 'SendQueue'?

Answer (score 0):

`configurator.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 8;`

Sets the default endpoint concurrent message limit to 8. That’s it.

Since you are specifying both `ConcurrentMessageLimit` and `PrefetchCount` on each receive endpoint, the default concurrent message limit is overridden, essentially unused in this configuration. Each receive endpoint will prefetch up to 25 messages and process up to 5 concurrently (up to 10 concurrent messages total across both receive endpoints).

Comment: Thanks for answer Chris. Is there a way to achieve total limit over both endpoints and prioritize one endpoint over the other?

Comment: Not that I know of, but RabbitMQ does have built-in priority queues. You can check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68320165/1882) on how to use them.