# Set message priority RabbitMQ/Masstransit?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, servicebus

By following [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html), I succeed in setting the priority for the RabbitMQ's messages with `x-max-priority` attribute (the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221020/rabbitmq-3-5-and-message-priority)), the received messages are prioritized. But I can't do the same thing with the MassTransit. I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320009/change-message-priority-with-masstransit-rabbitmq) but it also doesn't work. Here is my MassTransit configuration:

**Producer's Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("username");
            h.Password("password");
        });

        cfg.EnablePriority(10);
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

**Producer's OrdersController.cs**

```
[HttpPost("SendOrders")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendOrders(IList<Order> orders)
{
    foreach(var order in orders)
    {
        await _busControl.Publish(order, context =>
        {
            context.SetPriority(order.Priority);
        });

        _logger.LogInformation($"Sent order: {order.Id} - {order.Name}");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Priority { get; set; }
}
```

**In Consumer's Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        configurator.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("username");
            h.Password("password");
        });

        //configurator.EnablePriority(10);

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("order-queue", c =>
        {
            c.EnablePriority(10);
            c.Consumer<OrderConsumer>();
        });
    });
});
```

**OrderConsumer.cs:**

```
public class OrderConsumer : IConsumer<Order>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Order> context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received order: {context.Message.Id} - {context.Message.Name}");
    }
}
```

The messages come randomly and not follow my priority, even I move the `c.EnablePriority` out to `ReceiveEndpoint()`method. Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the RabbitMQ Management Console, verify the queue has the priority attribute. And then, stop the consumer, produce a message, and verify that the priority is properly set on the message in the queue.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson for your response. I've checked the RabbitMQ local host, the queue has Priority attribute (with the "P" character in the feature), the messages also have priority when I get them from the queue.

Comment: Could you please help to check if my MassTransit configurations in Producer and Consumer are all correct or not? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify a `PrefetchCount` of 1, messages are going to be pulling from the queue and processed up to the specified prefetch count.

If there are 7 messages waiting, with a mix of priorities, and the PrefetchCount is 8, all 7 will be read and processed concurrently.